# Getting io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.UiAutomator2Exception error

Tags: java, android, junit, automation, appium

I write automation for Android TV streaming app, I have problem to run the test. When I'm trying to run test , i got error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.UiAutomator2Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Namespace with prefix 'com.onoapps.some.dev' has not been declared.

Anyone know what the problem is?

I'm using:

- Xiaomi miBox.
- Java
- Appium
- JUnit

That's what I was trying to do.

```
        public class RemoteControl extends AppiumBaseClass {

            public RemoteControl(AppiumDriver driver) {
                PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
            }

            @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//com.onoapps.some.dev:id/topRootId[@focusable='true']")
            private MobileElement currentTab;

            public String getCurrentTabName() {
                MobileElement tabText = currentTab.findElement(By.id("com.onoapps.some.dev:id/topBarItemTextViewId"));
                return tabText.getText();
            }
        }

        public class SeriesScreenFlows extends BaseTestClass {
            public void getSeriesTab(){
        getCurrentTabName();
            }
        }

        public class BaseTestClass extends AppiumBaseClass {

            public WebDriverWait wait;
            public Series_screen series_screen;
            public RemoteControl remoteControl;


            @Before
            public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
                AppiumController.instance.start();
                series_screen = new Series_screen(driver());
                remoteControl = new RemoteControl(driver());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include you app package when you locate a [MobileElement](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/MobileElement.html) by [ID](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/) so change this line:

```
MobileElement tabText = currentTab.findElement(By.id("com.onoapps.some.dev:id/topBarItemTextViewId"));
```

to this

```
MobileElement tabText = currentTab.findElement(By.id("topBarItemTextViewId"));
```

and your test should start working as expected.

Alternatively if you want to use [XPath](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-xpath-selector)

```
MobileElement tabText = currentTab.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='com.onoapps.some.dev:id/topBarItemTextViewId']"));
```

More information: [AS - Run your existing Appium tests](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/AS+-+Run+your+existing+Appium+tests)