# Python Appium Cannot Remote Emulator

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, appium, appium-android

I was try running manual appium is work to open my emulator in appium inspector, and then i try create simple script. here is my script :

```
from appium import webdriver
import time

desired_capabilities = {}

desired_capabilities['appPackage'] = 'com.facebook.lite'
desired_capabilities['appActivity'] = 'com.facebook.lite.MainActivity'
desired_capabilities['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_capabilities['deviceName'] = 'VirtualDevice'
desired_capabilities['udid'] = 'emulator-5554'

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/', desired_capabilities)
```

but after run the script show this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ATHAMZ-PC/Desktop/Python ADB/Python Bot/fb.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/', desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\ATHAMZ-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 274, in __init__
    AppiumConnection(command_executor, keep_alive=keep_alive), desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy
  File "C:\Users\ATHAMZ-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\ATHAMZ-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 364, in start_session
    response = self.execute(RemoteCommand.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\ATHAMZ-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ATHAMZ-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
```

whats is wrong with my script?

appium and inspector image to reference
[Appium Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t8Q6.png)
[Appium Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYO9N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but from your logs, try to remove the last `/` from `wd/hub/`.

```
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_capabilities)
```

Comment: I have some issue again after tes more script :(
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Namespace with prefix 'com.android.packageinstaller' has not been declared.

Comment: It looks like the other issue, you might create a new question with more details. Attach please your appium code and server logs, so it would be easier to understand the cause..

Comment: @garonx I've found the similar issue here, so maybe this will help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696092/getting-io-appium-uiautomator2-common-exceptions-uiautomator2exception-error